# NetWork Setup with 2 routers

Tags: networking

I have this:

Internet connects to a router and it's 192.168.2.1
I have a second router and it's 192.168.1.1 TP-Link Wireless Router

How can I have internet on the second router? I used LAN(192.168.2.1) to WAN(192.168.1.1) and I dont have internet on the TP-link.

Comment: Do you want I have two networks or one with two routers?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, the easiest is to set up the  TP-link router as a switch or an access point, try turning off the DHCP server on the TP-LINK, or seeing if it has an **AP** mode or similar

The other is hooking up the lan ports and manually editing DHCP ranges (I had to do this once and it has never worked as well as I wanted) I can try to find the instructions for that if the above doesn't work.